# How can I correctly type-pun?

Tags: c, emulation, type-punning, z80

Follow-up to extended discussion in [How can I determine if I'm overparenthesizing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55419302/casting-behavior-in-c)

I'm trying to emulate a Z80 in C, where several 8-bit registers can be combined to create 16-bit registers.

This is the logic I'm trying to use:

```
struct {
    uint8_t b;
    uint8_t c;
    uint16_t *bc;
} regs[1];
...
regs->bc = (uint16_t *)&(regs->b);
```

Why is this incorrect, and how can I do it correctly (using type-punning if needed)?

I need to do this multiple times, preferably within the same structure.

Comment: @FiddlingBits Because I didn't know how to use `union`s then. Now I realize what I could've done (although it's easier in C++ where I can use abstractions instead of `union`s). Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's incorrect because `b` is of type `uint8_t` and a pointer to `uint16_t` cannot be used for accessing such a variable. It might not be correctly aligned and it is a [strict aliasing violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule).

You are however free to do `(uint8_t *)&regs` or `(struct reg_t*)&regs->b`, since (6.7.2.1/15)

> A pointer to a structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member and vice versa.

---

When doing hardware-related programming, make sure to never use signed types. That means changing `intn_t` to `uintn_t`.

As for how to type pun properly, use a union:

```
typedef union
{
  struct                 /* standard C anonymous struct */
  {
    uint8_t b;
    uint8_t c;
  };
  uint16_t bc;
} reg_t;
```

You can then assign this to point at a 16 bit hardware register like this:

```
volatile reg_t* reg = (volatile reg_t*)0x1234;
```

where `0x1234` is the hardware register address.

NOTE: this union is endianess-dependent. `b` will access the MS byte of `bc` on big endian systems, but the LS byte of `bc` on little endian systems.

Answer (score 3):

To emulate a hardware register that can be accessed as two eight-bit registers or one 16-bit register, you can use:

```
union
{
    struct { int8_t b, c; };
    int16_t bc;
} regs[1];
```

Then `regs->bc` will be the 16-bit register, and `regs->b` and `regs->c` will be 8-bit registers.

Note: This uses an anonymous `struct` so that `b` and `c` appears as if they were members of the union. If the `struct` had a name, like this:

```
union
{
    struct { int8_t b, c; } s;
    int16_t bc;
} regs[1];
```

then you would have to include its name when accessing `b` or `c`, as with `regs->s.b`. However, C has a feature that allows you to use a declaration without a name for this purpose.

Also note this requires a C compiler. C allows using unions to reinterpret data. C++ has different rules.

Comment: I wonder if this can lead to problems because `b`, `c`, and `bc` are all signed.

Comment: I'd expect the Z80 to have a certain endian, yet the emulation environment's endian may not match.  That also needs eventual resolution by OP's code.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way is through anonymous unions in C as already shown in other answers. But as you want to process bytes, you may use the special handling of characters in the strict aliasing rule: whatever the type, is is always legal to use a char pointer to access the bytes of its representation. So this is conformant C

```
struct {
    uint16_t bc;
    uint8_t *b;
    uint8_t *c;
} regs[1];

regs->b = (uint8_t *) &(regs->bc);
regs->c = regs->b + 1
```

Interestingly enough, it is still valid for a C++ compiler...

Comment: Note: not detailed in answer, but when `uint8_t` type is defined in a C implementation it shall be `unsigned char` because: 1/ the size of any type must be a multiple of the size of `char` 2/ the size of `char` is at least 8 bits (5.2.4.2.1 Sizes of integer types `<limits.h>`) 3/ the size of `uint8_t` is exactly 8 bits.

Comment: You mean `regs->b = (uint8_t*) &regs->bc;` yeah? And well, you are always allowed to wildly convert pointers. The special rule you refer to is regarding iterating through any type byte-by-byte and lvalue access them (6.3.2.3/7).

Comment: The author will definitely be aware, but since nobody has said it out loud: this assumes a little-endian architecture. Which is a very safe assumption nowadays, but not something you can assume — so this is conformant C but technically won't necessarily work as expected everywhere.

Answer (score -1):

The correct way to type-pun in C (or do almost anything, for that matter), is to use an implementation that is configured to be suitable for one's intended purpose.  The Standard deliberately allows implementations that are intended for various purposes to behave in ways that would make them unsuitable for other purposes.  According to the authors, it was never intended to suggest that programs whose behavior isn't mandated by the Standard (but would be defined on the implementations for which they were intended) should be viewed as "broken".  Compilers whose authors seek to support the needs of their customers will recognize straightforward type-punning constructs whether or not the Standard requires them to do so, and optimizers who authors view their customers' needs with contempt should not be trusted to reliably handle anything complicated.